# Facing Issue with Error: Specified EntryPointExe '' was not found in the project outputs

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, windows-application-packaging

I am using VS2022 (17.5.3) with WPF App .net7.0.  I am building an app to be published in the Microsoft store.

I am facing error "Specified EntryPointExe '' was not found in the project outputs.". I searched a lot for what is causing this error, but i failed.

Following is the configuration of my main project file.

```
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <!--<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>-->
    <!--<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>-->
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
```

Also referencing a CommonLibrary.csproj with is based on .NET Standard 2.0

I created an Application Packaging Project with target framework "windows 10 version 2004 (10.0;build 19041)."  I added reference to main application, created required images, Associated project with store.

But during compilation, I am getting error "Specified EntryPointExe '' was not found in the project outputs".

I am badly stuck here. can anyone guide please ?

Regards

Comment: There is a typo: `TargetFrameworks` should be singular: `TargetFramework`

Comment: It's not a typo if you want to do multi-targeting, but just WAP one of the targets.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure there is a typo in your project file.
The node `TargetFrameworks` should be singular: `TargetFramework` (as it is in your first out-commented line)

So this should work:

```xml
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <!--<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>-->
    <!--<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>-->
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
```