# Facing an Issue with Error: "Specified EntryPointExe '' was not found in the project outputs

Tags: visual-studio-2022, winui-3, .net-7.0

I am using visual studio 2022. I first created a desktop app in .net5. The project build successfully.
Then I opted to upgrade the application to .net7. The application has no issues but upon building I get the error: Specified EntryPointExe 'Myapp.exe' was not found in the project outputs.

The experience is the same as to what Neha points here:[Specified EntryPointExe not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75868961/facing-issue-with-error-specified-entrypointexe-was-not-found-in-the-project)

Here is the Property Group configuration:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.22000.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <AssetTargetFallback>net5.0-windows$(TargetPlatformVersion);$(AssetTargetFallback)   </AssetTargetFallback>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <AppxPackageSigningEnabled>false</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur if there is a mismatch between the target framework of your application and the version of the .NET SDK that is installed on your machine.

First, you should check that the target framework of your application is set to `.NET 7`.

And then make sure the `.NET 7 SDK` is installed on your machine.

You could also try to check the output path for your project is set correctly.